# Rolling back Server edition from GRUB List (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, grub, ubuntu-10.04

I seems i did some mistake, and installed Ubuntu server on my home based ubuntu box.

and the problem is that GRUB places the server edition as a priority boot in the menu, especially when I upgrade the kernel or the release.

How can I remove the server from the GRUB menu permanently? can I un-install Ubuntu server edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your /boot/grub/menu.lst to change it to be what you want.  You can do this manually (how I've always done it), but there's also at least one GRUB menu editor [KGrubEditor](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=75442) that will help you do this.

Comment: thanks for showing me the location of the menu file
now I know the name of the image I was supposed to remove, I was about to comment out this line from the GRUB menu, but instead removed the 2.6.32-22-server package and all related packages.
now no need to comment it out because it should be removed by the synaptic package manager